# How to retrieve json obj value in my jsp web project from a form

Tags: java, json, forms, jsp

In mydemo.java I have this code:

```java
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
    ServletException, IOException {
        JsonObject person = new JsonObject();
        person.addProperty("firstName", "Andrew");
        person.addProperty("lastName", "Coolins");
        person.addProperty("address", " xx september");

String person= request.getParameter("firstname");
```

and my output for json string is:

```
{"firstName":"Andrew","lastName":"Coolins","address":" xx september"}
```

In mydemo2.java in method post, I want to add something like this:

```java
String jsonobj= request.getParameter("firstname"); //for example
request.setAttribute("firstname", firstname);       //for example
request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

My question is, how can I retrieve values for example "firstname" of json obj from a form in my index.jsp when the user insert data for firstname and then clicks on submit button? Can you explain to me with code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you can add something like this to your jsp page

```
<form method=post action =someServlet>
      <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
      <input type=submit  value="Do something"/>
</form>
```

Then in your servlet

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
        //do something
    }
```

I didn’t fully understand the question, did you ask about this?